# Turn off SSH while using Vagrant and AWS

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am trying to use Vagrant to boot Windows servers on AWS and after the machine starts Vagrant will always try to ssh into the machines. Is there any way to turn this off? There doesn't seem to be any documentation on skipping ssh during the configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, no there isn't. There are several bugs in the [vagrant-aws github repository](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws) that cover this, some of which talk about workarounds:

- https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/180
- https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/search?q=ssh+windows&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93